# Iterating nodes in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple question where I have to iterate DOM using Jquery(not Javascript). The div with class "questionBlock" can go on and on.
How do I access all the values of "class" that is inside optionContainer and store them in a json.

```
  <div class = "questionBlock"> 
    <div class = "title">title1</div>
    <div class = "optionContainer">
        <div class = "row">1</div>
        <div class = "row"> 2 </div>
        <div class = "row"> 3 </div>
        <div class = "row"> 4 </div>
        <div class = "row"> 5 </div>
        <div class = "row"> 6 </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class = "questionBlock"> 
    <div class = "title">title2</div>
    <div class = "optionContainer">
        <div class = "row">7</div>
        <div class = "row"> 8 </div>
        <div class = "row"> 13 </div>
        <div class = "row"> 24 </div>
        <div class = "row"> 15 </div>
        <div class = "row"> 16 </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class = "questionBlock"> 
    <div class = "title">title3</div>
    <div class = "optionContainer">
        <div class = "row">41</div>
        <div class = "row"> 42 </div>
        <div class = "row"> 43 </div>
        <div class = "row"> 44 </div>
        <div class = "row"> 45 </div>
        <div class = "row"> 46 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the values from all "rows" in all of the `optionContainer`s or all of the "rows" within a specific `optionContainer`?

Comment: You should not put spaces before or after the equals signs in the html. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp

Comment: I want values from all "rows" in all "optionContainer"

Comment: can you give an example of what you want the json to look like?

Comment: See my answer. It iterates first through each `.questionBlock`, and then through each item within.

Comment: And guys, please remember, I want to access the value of title too

Answer (score 0):

This will store the content of all `row` elements in a json object with each key named after the row number. (Check the console to see the resultant object):

```js
var stuff = {};

$('.optionContainer .row').each(function(){
   var curKey = 'row'+ $('.row').index($(this));
  stuff[curKey]=$(this).html().trim();
});
console.log(stuff);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#side-menu">
<div class="questionBlock"> 
    <div class="title">title1</div>
    <div class="optionContainer">
        <div class="row">1</div>
        <div class="row"> 2 </div>
        <div class="row"> 3 </div>
        <div class="row"> 4 </div>
        <div class="row"> 5 </div>
        <div class="row"> 6 </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="questionBlock"> 
    <div class="title">title2</div>
    <div class="optionContainer">
        <div class="row">7</div>
        <div class="row"> 8 </div>
        <div class="row"> 13 </div>
        <div class="row"> 24 </div>
        <div class="row"> 15 </div>
        <div class="row"> 16 </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="questionBlock"> 
    <div class="title">title3</div>
    <div class="optionContainer">
        <div class="row">41</div>
        <div class="row"> 42 </div>
        <div class="row"> 43 </div>
        <div class="row"> 44 </div>
        <div class="row"> 45 </div>
        <div class="row"> 46 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply use `.each()` in jQuery.

https://api.jquery.com/each/

```
$(".questionBlock").each(function(parentIndex) {
    $(this).each(function(childindex) {
        // do logic
    });
});
```

Comment: I did this but I see that the values are repeating

Comment: With `$(this).each()` or with `$(".row").each()`? Using the `this` identifier should work.

Comment: I basically want to iterate over all div having classname as "optionContainer" and all rows inside this optionContainer, having class "row". The classnames are important.

Comment: @Avishekgurung, have you verified my answer? Have you verified `console` of your browser ?